# Output random words

Tags: php, html, arrays, random, words

I have to write a program that will output random words(with random letters) and that will not have 3 vocals or consonants near, so i wrote:

```
$array = array();                                 
$n = 10;                                               

for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    $l = rand(4, 10);  //$l = word length
?>

<br>

<?

for ($j = 0; $j < $l; $j++) {

    $cas = rand(65, 90);  //$cas=random letters
    $array[$j] = $cas; 

    if($j > 1) {    
        if (($array[$j-1] == 65 || $array[$j-1] == 69 || $array[$j-1] == 73 || $array[$j-1] == 79 || $array[$j-1] == 85) ^ ($array[$j-2] == 65|| $array[$j-2] == 69 || $array[$j-2] == 73 || $array[$j-2] == 79 || $array[$j-2] == 85)) {  //will do XOR '^'

            $cas = rand(65, 90);                                                           
            $array[$j] = $cas;                          

        }

    }

    $m = chr($array[$j]);   
    echo $m;
    }
}


?>

</body>
</html>
```

don't know why but it seems that IF doesn't work, 'because when it outputs it'll print also words with 3 or more consonants or vocal.
Can anybody help me? thanks :D and sorry for bad english :P

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

So what have I done here?

In the first part I have defined the array `$characters` which contains all characters e.g.`[a-zA-Z]`. Then I also have `$vowels` which contains all vowels e.g. `[aAeEiIoOuU]`. And I also defined `$consonants` which contains all consonants.

After this I mixed the entire `$characters` array with [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) and took `$length` array elements from the start with [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

Then I checked the `$randomWord` with the function `check()`, which goes through each character of the random word and checks if the next 3 characters are either vowels or consonants. I do this with [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if the character is in the associated array e.g. `$vowels` or `$consonants`. If yes I change middle character of the row to the opposite e.g. `vowels` -> `consonants` | `consonants` -> `vowels`. And if no row either of vowels or consonants are found it returns the random word.

At the end I just use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with [`chr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) to go through each array element and change it from ASCII to the matching character.

To print it I used [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to append each character together.

```
<?php

    $characters = array_merge(range(65, 90), range(97, 122));
    $vowels = array(65, 97, 69, 101, 73, 105, 79, 111, 85, 117);
    $consonants  = array(66, 98, 67, 99, 68, 100, 70, 102, 71, 103, 72, 104, 74, 106, 75, 107, 76, 108, 77, 109, 78, 110, 80, 112, 81, 113, 82, 114, 83, 115, 84, 116, 86, 118, 87, 119, 88, 120, 89, 121, 90, 122);
    $randomWord = "";
    $length = rand(4, 10);

    shuffle($characters);
    $randomWord = array_slice($characters, 0, $length);

    function check($randomWord, $vowels, $consonants) {

        foreach($randomWord as $key => $randomCharacter) {

            //Check for vowels
            if(in_array($randomWord[$key], $vowels) && ( isset($randomWord[$key+1]) && in_array($randomWord[$key+1], $vowels) ) && ( isset($randomWord[$key+2]) && in_array($randomWord[$key+2], $vowels) )) {
                $randomWord[$key+1] = $consonants[array_rand($consonants, 1)];
                check($randomWord, $vowels, $consonants);   
            } 

            //Check for consonants
            if(in_array($randomWord[$key], $consonants) && ( isset($randomWord[$key+1]) && in_array($randomWord[$key+1], $consonants) ) && ( isset($randomWord[$key+2]) && in_array($randomWord[$key+2], $consonants) )) {
                $randomWord[$key+1] = $vowels[array_rand($vowels, 1)];
                check($randomWord, $vowels, $consonants);
            } 

        }

        return $randomWord;     
    }

    $randomWord = check($randomWord, $vowels, $consonants);
    echo $randomWord = implode("", array_map("chr", $randomWord));

?>
```

Example outputs:

```
YeVIkufuhv
lEMObi
VosaKAzIRb
qOyoK
IBoVIQahIg
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I think it's a good idea, despite I can't change what I had already wrote, so i have to follow the code into the question! thanks anyway!

Comment: @Mattia Why can't you change?

Comment: Someone told me to do this program like that :)

Comment: @Mattia I don't think your attempt which you have is very fast and also not very easy to read

Comment: I know man but in the first part I choose randomly length and characters, then I have to check the word (not 3 consonants etc.).. tha's all! I just need check, IF or WHILE, and how to do it!

Comment: @Mattia I have to say it your code is a little bit messed up, so I would use my code and this guy which said that you should use your, show him my code! And stick with it

Answer (score 1):

This code is private for me you can use it

```
function random_string($hashstring=null,$randLengh=null)
    {
        $string = $hashstring;
        $randLengh =$randLengh;
        if ($string == null) {
            $string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        }
        $charactersLength = strlen($string);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $randLengh; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $string[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }

        return $randomString;
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately I forgot to say that I have to use ASCII code so I can't define a variable that contains all the characters!